# Selenium org.seleniumhq.selenium 3.141.59 - org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException on URI /status

Tags: selenium

During the selenium test execution, for some reason, there is a random port checker on URI

*/status*

and looks like that

```
org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:9638/status]
```

The Selenium java client is trying with different/random TCP ports.

We are using Selenium Grid and there is one correct node registered and ready to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:9638/status]
```

...implies that there is a issue with the [**guava**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284776/incompatible-library-version-selenium-guava/50287063#50287063) version.

Two major reasons for this error are as follows:

- Presence of multiple versions of [guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65973443/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-java-util-stream-collector-com-google-common-colle/65973602#65973602).
- Incompatible version of [guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634492/org-openqa-selenium-remote-service-driverservicebuilder-createargslcom-google/57658406#57658406).

---

### Solution

A potential solution would be to replace all the existing/previous versions of [guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014053/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-p/52034052#52034052) with the latest version. However, the best solution will be to upgrade to the latest [**Selenium**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) ***v4.1.0***.